# Dividing Sound Into Equal Frequency Ranges with pyaudio

Tags: fft, pyaudio

I'm trying to build audio reactive leds as a little project. I'm using an api to interact with leds via computer. What I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to divide the audio stream into frequency ranges. For example, if I divide by 100Hz, a 22100 Hz solo channel should provide 221 groups. Then I want to assign each group to a led or leds and do effects with the normalized mean value of the groups.How can I accomplish this? I've been reading about FFT and tried some sample codes but so far I've failed. I can't seem to get my head around this. Below is the closest project that I've found online. I've tweaked around with it and I'm able to control my leds but I just can't, for example, isolate the first 100 Hz.

https://gist.github.com/limitedmage/2245892

Comment: I think, until you can do it on paper and understand the math, you probably won't be able to code it.  If there's a problem understanding the math, maybe you can ask on the Math Stack Exchange. Or better, the DSP stack exchange.

Comment: @rewolf I totally agree with you. However it seemed such an advanced topic for a small project. So, I thought someone might basically explain it or point me towards a direction in terms of coding.

Comment: I suggest you invest many hours/days/months to understand the Fourier Transform then watch this video which brings together the essential concepts to send your time series buffer into a FFT library ... its the money shot ... if this video does not ring true then rinse and repeat https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkGsMWi_j4Q # Discrete Fourier Transform - Simple Step by Step - fft